# pdfcrop doesn't work

Tags: pdf

I just installed pdfcrop to use to crop my exported Visio .pdf diagrams for use in LaTeX (MikiTex with TexMaker).

I have a file called PDF_TEST.pdf that is exported from Visio 2019,
[image]

I run the following command in Windows PowerShell

```
pdfcrop --verbose PDF_TEST.pdf PDF_TEST_CROP.pdf
```

It outputs:

```
PDFCROP 1.38, 2012/11/02 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.
* PDF header: %PDF-1.7
* Running ghostscript for BoundingBox calculation ...
MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.25 (2018-09-13)
Copyright (C) 2018 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 596 842
* Page 1: 0 0 596 842
%%HiResBoundingBox: 0.738000 0.000000 595.493982 841.517974
* Running pdfTeX ...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 2.9.7300 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(tmp-pdfcrop-11692.tex [1 <./PDF_TEST.pdf>] )
Output written on tmp-pdfcrop-11692.pdf (1 page, 2408 bytes).
Transcript written on tmp-pdfcrop-11692.log.
pdftex: major issue: So far, no MiKTeX administrator has checked for updates.
==> 1 page written on `PDF_TEST_CROP.pdf'.
pdfcrop: major issue: So far, no MiKTeX administrator has checked for updates.
```

The resulting PDF_TEST_CROP.pdf looks like this:
[image]

**It looks the exact same! No change. When I use it in my LaTeX document, it shows all the white space.**

Comment: Might be an idea to upload that file to somewhere so others can have a look at it.

Comment: Perhaps the file has some border or similar that pdfcrop takes as content. Btw: `pdftex: major issue: So far, no MiKTeX administrator has checked for updates.` means that you should check for updates in the console in user **and** admin mode.